# React InstantSearch - Not filtering by date using "filters" inside of "<Configure />"

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

so I'm using React InstantSearch for my react project and I'm running into a snag where I can't seem to filter by date. I've followed the documentation found here for filtering by a date, yet no results are returning.

I have my dates stored as ISO strings and just to test the functionality, I have converted them to Unix timestamps in my code:

```
<InstantSearch
    appId={'appId'}
    apiKey={'my-api-key'}
    indexName={'storeName'}
>
   <Configure filters="createdAt>=1501688239.446 AND createdAt<=1510132435.88" />
   <SearchHit user={this.props.user} />
</InstantSearch>
```

The ISO dates are stored with the key `createdAt` and I have copied the dates directly from Algolia to make sure I was getting exact values. However for some reason...no results are coming back and there are no errors. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you make an example of your problem using codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: You can also test this filter out in the Algolia dashboard

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this to work? This has been one of the most frustrating things I've ever implemented.